# hoverIntent() not a function

Tags: jquery, hover, hoverintent

I can't seem to get hoverIntent plugin to work.  It's definitely loading jQuery and hoverIntent. But, .hoverIntent() is "not a function". (.hover() works fine).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#portfolio-circle').hoverIntent(
        function() {
            $('#portfolio-hover').fadeTo('normal', 1);
            $('#portfolio-caption').fadeTo('normal', 1);
        },
        function() {
            $('#portfolio-hover').fadeTo('normal', 0);
            $('#portfolio-caption').fadeTo('normal', 0);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any js error on page load other than this error?

Comment: *"It's definitely loading...hoverIntent."* How did you verify this? What happens if you (temporarily) use a direct link to the file hosted by the developer? http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js

Comment: There are no other js errors.
The hoverIntent js file is definitely loading because firebug shows it as loaded under the "Net" tab.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check whether you are referencing two different versions of jquery by mistake. I faced a similar error with jqueryui where everything was loading fine, but I realized later that there were two different versions of jquery being referenced.

Comment: You're right. The CMS I'm using automatically loaded its own (earlier) version of jQuery. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It should be nice if jQuery makes a check if a previous version is already defined.. thank you for the help