# Ubermenu Submenu not displaying Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Website here:

http://www.serviced-lettings.co.uk/?theme=new-serviced

That is a new theme i am working on, ubermenu is installed and the sub-menu appears in firefox correctly on hover, i can see in firebug that it alters the inline css to display: block. When in chrome or safari the drop down doesnt display no errors.

Any one has any thoughts as to why? latest version of wordpress and uber

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.hoverIntent is not a function  -- ubermenu.min.js:206
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903624/hoverintent-not-a-function) indicates, it may be a problem with multiple versions of jQuery, though the [ubermenu documentation](http://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/settings/menu/trigger) claims not to use jQuery.